# Refrencing data in other paths issue with firebase security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm using firebase realtime database to make a pokemon-go style game.

For each user they have a data structure like this:

[image]

Each entry in the "pokemon" node has an ID which corresponds with an ID in the "tapped pokemon" node.

I want to use security rules to ensure that no one can create a new node in the "pokemon" node that has an ID that exists in the "tappedpokemon" node.

I've been trying to use a rule like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        "tappedpokemon" : {
          "$id" : {
            ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()",
          }
        },
        "pokemon" : {
          "$mon" : {
            ".write": "!data.parent().parent().child('tappedpokemon').child(newData.child('id').val()).exists() && !data.exists()",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this code is producing true every time.

```
firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + 
  "/tappedpokemon/" + "784193e6-6f94-49a1-958d-877080460a38").set(true);

pokemon_inventory_ref.push({id: "784193e6-6f94-49a1-958d-877080460a38", 
  name:"Lapras", lat:20, lng:38, date:Date.now(), 
  iv: Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 20 + 1)) + 20});
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: At first glance the rule look good for what you describe. Can you show the code of how you call this, preferably with hard-coded values that match what you have in the JSON you shared?

Comment: I'm using firebase for the web to do this:

https://pastebin.com/5h4Mk9Nh

The code is run, in order, twice. On the first time everything runs without a permission error. On the second, I get an error for the "tappedpokemon" set being denied but not any errors for the "pokemon" node and sure enough duplicate pokemon are being added.

Also "pokemon_inventory_ref" is a reference to the pokemon_inventory node for a user, and i've hardcoded some of the values which are normally dynamic.

Comment: A simple improvement would be to use the `id` as the key. So `pokemon_inventory_ref.child("784193e6-6f94-49a1-958d-877080460a38").set({ name:"Lapras", lat:20, lng:38, date:Date.now(), 
  iv: Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 - 20 + 1)) + 20});`. Since that isn't the problem you're struggling with, it's not an answer. But if you want the IDs to be unique in a parent node, that would be more idiomatic. It would also make the rules a bit simpler, with `newData.child('id').val()` becoming `$mon`.

Comment: I added the code from your pastebin to the question. Please make any edits there. What is `pokemon_inventory_ref` in this code? (sorry for asking so many questions, but this code once again seems fine at first glance)